# T-SQL Parallel execution when using CREATE?

Tags: sql, t-sql, data-warehouse

If I have a single T-SQL script that looks like this, and each table individually takes 10 minutes to write to the database, will the total script time be 10 mins or 20 mins? I.e. is parallel writing to a DataWarehouse of multiple tables supported in a single T-SQL Scipt?:

-- Query Window 1

```sql
CREATE TABLE Table1 (
    Column1 INT,
    Column2 VARCHAR(50)
)
CREATE TABLE Table2 (
    ID INT PRIMARY KEY,
    Name VARCHAR(50)
);
```

Comment: So you have something like INSERT INTO Table1...? If so, try INSERT INTO Table1 WITH(TABLOCK). Still not running in parallel but faster inserts

Comment: You say you have a single script, but then state you have different queries open in different windows, which implies *separate* scripts. Which is it? In simplest terms, however, yes SQL Server is perfectly capable of running multiple concurrent transactions against different (unrelated) objects. If, however, you have some kind of relationship between the 2 then you will likely *need* to `INSERT` the data sequentially, as you can't put data into the second table until the related data is in the first.

Comment: You are probably better off doing a parallel insert into a single table see https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sql-server-blog/real-world-parallel-insert-select-what-else-you-need-to-know/ba-p/305329 and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008/dd425070(v=sql.100) You need `TABLOCKX` and an empty table.

Comment: It is a single script. I can’t use insert or anything like that, since I’m creating 2 new tables from a Lakehouse delta table. The two tables do not depend on each other. The only difference, in some other columns not shown, is a filter, for a different country. So is the total time 10 or 20 mins?

Comment: If you create 2 tables in the script and don't insert anything than running your script should be instantly, not 10 minutes

Comment: Yes, its not really 10 minutes, but its's a hypothetical just to understand if its executed serially or in parallel, which was my original queston